# python gpg.decrypt outputfile is empty

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

My code:

```
import gnupg
import os

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))+'\GnuPG')

fiele = open ("nchrcht.txt",'rb')
cypher = gpg.encrypt_file(fiele, recipients='Dovahkiin@Mailkrypto.de',output="return.txt.gpg")
fiele.close()

with open('nchrcht.txt.gpg', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(
        file=f,
        passphrase='123456789123456789',
        output='decrypted.txt',
    )

print(status.ok)
print(status.status)
print(status.stderr)
```

Output:

```
True decryption ok 

[GNUPG:] ENC_TO DA763F0E7792F282 1 0 

[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED D21A9E4163E62171287CBE44DA763F0E7792F282 0 

[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED D21A9E4163E62171287CBE44DA763F0E7792F282 0 

[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_KEY D21A9E4163E62171287CBE44DA763F0E7792F282D21A9E4163E62171287CBE44DA763F0E7792F282 u 

[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED D21A9E4163E62171287CBE44DA763F0E7792F282 0 gpg: verschlüsselt mit 4096-Bit RSA Schlüssel, ID DA763F0E7792F282, erzeugt 2020-12-04
      "Autogenerated Key <Dovahkiin@Mailkrypto.de>" 

[GNUPG:] BEGIN_DECRYPTION 

[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_COMPLIANCE_MODE 23 

[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_INFO 2 9 0 

[GNUPG:] PLAINTEXT 62 1607193430 

[GNUPG:] PLAINTEXT_LENGTH 0 

[GNUPG:] DECRYPTION_OKAY 

[GNUPG:] GOODMDC 

[GNUPG:] END_DECRYPTION
```

The encryption seems to work fine but when I decrypt I get an empty outputfile
Any help on what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm currently experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm experiencing the same when trying to decrypt a file on a linux alpine container